# ActiveMQ SecurityException: User name [defaultUser] or password is invalid

Tags: security, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I upgraded my servicemix from 4.4.2 to 5.5.0. There seems to be some security configuration i'm missing. The ActiveMQ version in servicemix is now 5.12. I see the following exception in the log file.

```
2016-01-19 12:30:47,760 | WARN  | 2.23:54741@61616 |Service | 95 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.11.1 | Security Error occurred: User name [defaultUser] or password is invalid.
2016-01-19 12:30:49,759 | INFO  | q-broker] Task-2 | TransportConnection | 95 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.11.1 | Stopping tcp://<APPServerIP>:54742 because Failed with SecurityException: User name [defaultUser] or password is invalid.
2016-01-19 12:31:17,767 | WARN  | 2.23:54746@61616 | TransportConnection | 95 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.11.1 | Failed to add Connection
ID:dkdl7011.dcsgomni.com-47989-1449791490993-0:21948
java.lang.SecurityException: User name [defaultUser] or password is invalid.
    at org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(SimpleAuthenticationBroker.java:85)[95:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addConnection(BrokerFilter.java:97)[95:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.11.1]
```

The IP shown in the log is of my WebsphereServer. The activeMQ console shows it as a consumer for my queue.

Can I find out what is the [defaultUser] being used? I have enabled anonymous user access in activemq.xml. Part of activemq.xml is pasted below.

```
    <plugins>
    <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="true">
    <users>
            <authenticationUser username="smx" password="pwd" groups="users,admins"/>
            <authenticationUser username="karaf" password="pwd" groups="users,admins"/>
            <authenticationUser username="system" password="pwd" groups="users,admins"/>
            <authenticationUser username="user" password="pwd" groups="users,admins"/>
            <authenticationUser username="defaultUser" password="pwd" groups="users,admins"/>
    </users>
    </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>

    <authorizationPlugin>
    <map>
      <authorizationMap>
        <authorizationEntries>
          <authorizationEntry queue=">" write="users,admins,anonymous" read="users,admins,anonymous" admin="users,admins,anonymous" />
          <authorizationEntry topic=">" write="users,admins,anonymous" read="users,admins,anonymous" admin="users,admins,anonymous" />
          <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="users,admins,anonymous" write="users,admins,anonymous" admin="users,admins,anonymous"/>
        </authorizationEntries>
      </authorizationMap>
    </map>
    </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter-properties.html) helped. The default credentials were defaultUser/defaultPassword. I updated it in activemq.xml and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was resolved by ensuring same password is defined in activemq.xml[mypwd] and in credentials.properties

activemq.xml

```
<simpleAuthenticationPlugin> 
<users>
<authenticationUser username="system" password="**mypwd**" groups="users,admins"/>
</users>
</simpleAuthenticationPlugin >
```

credentials.properties

```
activemq.username=system
activemq.password=password
```